# control height of flextable rows

Tags: flextable

I have a flextable and control the height of the rows with https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/height.html

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c("row1", "row2"),
                col2 = c("row1", "row2"),
                col3 = c("row1", "row2"),
                col4 = c("row1", "row2"),
                col5 = c("row1", "row2"),
                col6 = c("row1", "row2"))
ft = df %>%
  flextable() %>%
  width(1:6,rep(9/6,6)) %>%
  height(height = .1) %>%
  hrule(rule = "exact") %>%
  fontsize(size = 7, part = "all")
```

but when I adjust the height from `0.1` to `1.0` I get and save the image

```
save_as_image(ft,
              path = "file.png",
              zoom = 1,
              webshot = "webshot2")
```

I get the same image `0.97" high and 9.21" wide`

[image]

If possible, I would like to get the lines to be more compact as with excel where I get each row to be 24pixels (0.125")

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

it appears I can use the `line_spacing()` argument as well

```
ft = df %>%
  flextable() %>%
  width(1:6,rep(9/6,6)) %>%
  height(height = .1) %>%
  hrule(rule = "exact") %>%
  fontsize(size = 7, part = "all") %>%
  line_spacing(space = 0.25, part = "all")
```

[image]